# Are there water/wastewater utility GIS symbols for electronic markers?

Tags: cartography, symbology, standards

I hesitate to ask for standard symbols, but is there a de facto standard symbol(s)?  Or a popular set of symbols to use for electronic markers?

Our utility will soon start marking with electronic ball markers similar to these:
http://images.pennnet.com/articles/ww/thm/th_193172.jpg ([from Water World Article 'Municipality Marks New Pipelines for Future Access'](http://www.waterworld.com/index/display/article-display/241729/articles/waterworld/volume-21/issue-11/feature/municipality-marks-new-pipelines-for-future-access.html)).
[image]

I found this one somewhere, but I can't remember where I grabbed it from:
[image]

Are there others?

Comment: USA Standards??

Comment: USA for me, but I'll upvote others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is in arcmap 10. But somehow I don't think that is what you are looking for:)

[image]

Comment: I looked through the ArcMap 10 symbols prior to posting the question.  Are there electronic marker symbols in there and I missed it?

Comment: Duh, You said electronic not water or waste water. I'll have to learn what electronic markers are first. :o

Comment: The physical asset is called an electronic marker (as you can imagine, searching for `marker` returned a useless result set).  So I'm looking an electronic marker (map symbol) to represent an electronic marker (plastic balls that are buried w/ the underground asset).